# Numeric Synonyms

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have a list of old part numbers I wanted to add as synonyms in my solr index. The issue however is that they don't seem to be working. If I add normal text to my synonyms.txt file it works fine, but numeric synonyms return no results. Any ideas as to how to fix this?

-Paul

Comment: it ignores numbers not without reason

Comment: What is the definition of your field, what is the content of your synonym file, what does the "Analysis" page show, what are you indexing and how are you querying?